# measurement converter for selecting unit

Tags: ruby, units-of-measurement

I'm seeing quite a few measurement conversion relating gems, but I haven't been able to find one that will select the best/closest unit.

For example

If I give the gem the measurement of

```
9 inches + 6 inches
```

I'm trying to get the result

```
1 foot, 3 inches
```

The conversion tools I've seen, I'd have to tell the convertor to try to convert to feet, and then decide which is the most appropriate measurement.

Comment: Could you name those gems you're referring to?

Comment: Maybe not helpful but working: http://www.google.de/search?q=9+inches+%2B+6+inches%20in%20feet

Comment: @jan, ruby-units (http://units.rubyforge.org/) I believe is the most common gem. There is also ruby measure (https://github.com/mrkn/ruby-measure)

Comment: @arnep, the result is what I'm looking for, but I can't be sending my data to google to have them do the conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how complicated you wanted to get but for your example I did this:

```
def plain_english_conversion(inches)
    divmod_output = inches.divmod(12)
    puts "#{divmod_output[0]} ft, #{divmod_output[1]} in"
end

puts "15 "
plain_english_conversion(15)

puts "37 "
plain_english_conversion(37)
```

With the output of:

> 15
>
> 1 ft, 3 in
>
> 37
>
> 3 ft, 1 in

Certainly I restricted it to feet/inches but you can abstract it out if necessary (inches & yards, feet & yards, etc.)